# Hashtable crashes when retrieving value from table index

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a simple adt using hashtable, I was able to insert data object into their respective indexes. When I try to check a value inside `table[index]->data.GetName()` the program crashes.

Data class:

```
Data(string name, string value int value = 0) : name(name), value(value)
{

}

string Data::GetName() const
{
    return name;
}

string Data::GetValue() const
{
    return value;
}
```

Hash Table Class

```
   class HashT
{
public:
    HashT(ostream&) : size(0), cap(TBL_CAP), table(new hashnode*[TBL_CAP])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
        {
            table[i] = NULL;
        }
    };
    HashT()
    {
    };
    //~HashT();
    void HashT::Ins(Data& data)
    {
        size_t index = HashFunc(data.GetName());
        node * newData = new node(data);
        //if (table[index]->item.GetName() == data.GetName())
        // Do not insert;
        else
            newData->next = table[index];
            table[index] = newData;
            size++;
    }
    int  HashFunc(string name);

private:

    struct hashnode
    {
        Data item;
        hashnode* next;
        node(const Data& DataObj) : item(DataObj), next(NULL)
        {

        }
    };
    hashnode ** table;
    int size;
    Data data;
    int cap;

    const static int TBL_CAP = 3;
};
```

When I debugged, the program crashes at the point where `item` tries to perform `GetName()` via `table[index]->item.GetName()`, if I do `table[index]->item.GetName()` , the program also crashes. If I test for `table[index] == NULL` I do not get any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table[index]` may be NULL (and definitely is when you first start adding data). This means you can't access `table[index]->item` as that would be a NULL pointer dereference. You were on the right track with checking for NULL - you need to do both, check for NULL and then check the name. You can do this in one if test as follows:

```
if (table[index] != NULL && table[index]->item.GetName() == data.GetName())
```